# Module assets-webpack-plugin not being installed via npm install

Tags: angular, npm

From this package:

https://github.com/ansrivas/angular2-flask

An npm install from within it's front/ folder doesn't yield assets-webpack-plugin in node-modules/

However if I just use the https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter that it is based on and do an npm install in that, it does get installed.

The only difference I could find is that the packages.json file of the two has assets-webpack-plugin in dependencies: for angular2-flask and it is in devDependencies: for angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not fully understood. I'm guessing that it initially had some errors installing.

`npm install --production`

followed by a

`npm install`

and the 'assets-webpack-plugin/' finally did install. (This was after countless `npm install`s failing to get it there.)